# Objective-C++: is there an overhead in generated code compared to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, exception, module, objective-c++

Let's say you have an Obj-C module written in pure Obj-C. Does switching the extension to .mm mean that the generated code will be larger due to C++ exception handling (or something else maybe)?

Answer (score -1):

There are two possibilities: You either need Objective-C++ or you don't. If you don't need it, don't use it. If you need, well then you need it, so if there is memory overhead, there isn't much you can do about it.

Don't switch to Objective-C++ just for fun. I wouldn't use it for anything other than writing bridging code between Objective-C and C++.

Comment: "What happens when you switch from apples to oranges? -- Don't switch to oranges!" Downvoted because it doesn't answer the question.